# svn: E160013: '/svnroot/cmusphinx/trunk/cmuclmtk' path not found

Tags: cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I am trying :

```
sudo svn co https://cmusphinx.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/cmusphinx/trunk/cmuclmtk
```

But I get:

```
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://cmusphinx.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/cmusphinx/trunk/cmuclmtk'
svn: E160013: '/svnroot/cmusphinx/trunk/cmuclmtk' path not found
```

What is the problem and How can I fix it? I wanna use cmuclmtk to create a language model.

Comment: You already asked at https://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/help/thread/7b8f9ec7/